# htaccess urlrewriting error

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/$ categories.php?cat_name=$1
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ categories.php?cat_name=$1
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/([0-9]*)/$ categories.php?cat_name=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/([0-9]*)$ categories.php?cat_name=$1&page=$2
```

When a users opens this page mywebsite.com/cars/ it opens the first page of the category cars which is correct, but when they write mywebsite.co/cars/2 the code `$_GET['cat_name']` brings cars/2 which is wrong because the cat name is cars and 2 is the page number.

How to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sort your rules from the most specific to the least specific:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/([0-9]*)/$ categories.php?cat_name=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/([0-9]*)$ categories.php?cat_name=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/$ categories.php?cat_name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ categories.php?cat_name=$1 [L]
```

And make sure there are no other rules matched after a hit by using `[L]`.

Comment: thank you. it works. i will accept it in 10 min. but what does [L] do ?

Comment: L stands for last. Meaning no other rules will be checked after one rule matches.